# python string match time complexity

Tags: python, string, time, match, complexity-theory

I need help for this question. I think the time complexity is O(n), but my friend insists that this is O(n^2). one of reason is because of `fn = fn[index+1 ::]`

```
#filename: string_expression_matcher.cc
#string: stxpm.c
#should return



import sys
string = "string_expression_matcher.cc"
subStr = "stxpm.c"

fn = list(string)
for i in subStr:
    try:
        index = fn.index(i)
        fn = fn[index+1 ::]
    except:
        print ("can't dup")
        sys.exit()

print ("found")
```

Here is my algorithm:

1. s in subStr:

   - The loop starts at: "string_expression_matcher.cc"
   - The remaining string output of this step is: "tring_expression_matcher.cc"
2. t in subStr

   - The loop starts at: "tring_expression_matcher.cc"
   - The remaining is: "ring_expression_matcher.cc"
3. x in subStr

   - The loop starts at: "ring_expression_matcher.cc"
   - The remaining is: "pression_matcher.cc"
4. p in subStr

   - The loop starts at: "pression_matcher.cc"
   - The remaining is: "ression_matcher.cc"

and so on to last step.

Given:

```
n = len(subStr)
m = len(string)`
```

what is time complexity in this program?
Thanks for everyone, but i really want to know if O(n) or O(n^2). I know the code is not perfect but please focus on time complexity..
Thanks so much

Does anyone know how python string copy works? what happen when we do fn = fn[index+1 ::]?

I asked a distinguish engineer. he said the result is O(m*n). how about you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if we add item in either m or n , the time complexity is linear..."?

Comment: forgot my comment.  I want to know what is the time complexity of this program. please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm (in terms of number of comparisons) is `O(n)`, where `n` is length of the string. In the worst case both string and pattern will be the same and then for every character in `subStr` you will move to next character of `string`. It'll be equivalent to simple comparison of strings.

However your implementation may be `O(n^2)` in terms of other operations and the reason for this, as you mentioned in you question, is the following line:

```
fn = fn[index+1 ::]
```

This is effectively copying the string (assuming the slice above is implemented as a copy). If you consider previous example again, for every character in a string you'd have to copy all remaining characters, which is `O(n^2)`. This is because you'll be copying `n-1` characters first, then `n-2`, `n-3` and so on, and at the last iteration you will copy just one character. Total amount of items to be copied will be then `n-1`+`n-2`+`...`+`1`, which, as the [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), is equal to `(n-1)*((n-1)+1)/2 = (n-1)*n/2 = O(n^2)`. For other situations this could be generalised to `O(m*n)`, where `m` is length of the pattern.

What your friend might like to tell you was: your algorithm is linear, but your implementation is not. It can be easily solved though. Use solution presented by @thkang or something more transparent to get rid of hidden complexity, for example:

```
try:
  si = iter(string)
  for c in subStr:
    while c != si.next():
      pass
except StopIteration:
  print "no match"
else:
  print "match"
```

Comment: This is effectively copying the string. If you consider previous example again, for every character in a string you'd have to copy all remaining characters, which is obviously O(n^2). can you explain a little more? why does string copy cause O(n^2)? dont forget,the size of string is shrinking.  thanks

Comment: the size is shrinking, but it's still `(n-1)*n/2` copies to be done, which is `O(n^2)`. I've edited the answer to clarify a little bit more.

Comment: I just post another answer O(m*n). there are two different length of strings. one is m, another one is n. in the worst case is for every element in n , there are m element need to copy due to slice operation. therefore the answer is O(m*n). do you agree?

Comment: This is correct, but if `m == n` you have `O(n^2)`. You don't make any assumption about the shorter string (the pattern), so again: your worst case is two equal strings. `O(n*m)` is not really linear unless `n` or `m` are limited by a constant.

Comment: yes, he said it is not linear. I also raise your concern m==n and became O(n^2). he said yes only if you can prove m is always equal to n. he said it can't be presented as O(n^2)

Comment: Can we said the worst case is O(n^2) and the time complexity is O(m*n)?

Comment: You can prove `m<=n` where `m` is length of the pattern (for `m>n` it doesn't make sense to run the algorithm). This is why you can say worst-case time complexity is `O(n^2)`. But yes, `O(m*n)` is more accurate. Your initial question was simply linear vs quadratic though.

Comment: it is become more clear about this question. BTW, it seems I never see the notation O(m*n) in big O.it always O(n), O(n^2)... have you seen before? if yes, Can you post a link here.

Comment: Because normally you're only interested in a magnitude and not splitting the function to zillion of factors and putting them into the big-O. You often say the complexity is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the length of a longer string, etc. In your example `O(m*n)=O(n^2)` anyway as `m<=n`. Here is the link to [big-O with multiple variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables).

Comment: so which one is correct?  O(m*n) or O(n^2) when people question me about time complexity?

Comment: or which answer I suppose to give when people ask me time complexity of this question?

Comment: Both are correct as `n^2` is upper bound for `m*n`. You normally say `O(n^2)` to simply indicate the complexity is quadratic. If you say `O(m*n)` you'll give some more detail, so someone could for example say: _great, in my case `m` is always of size 3, so this is actually linear_. I'd say either `O(m*n)` or _quadratic_ depending on level of details someone would like to receive. Please open separate question regarding big-O notation to attract more answers if you want to dig the problem. We shouldn't really expand the original question to this level in the comments.

Comment: i think your answer is perfect. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer slightly to take into account our discussion here. Please accept if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but this is neither O(n) nor O(n+m). Both of them are better than O(n^2) and this algorithm is O(n^2). Why?

1. You iterate over source string which has O(n) complexity
2. In each iteration you call "index" on string which also has O(n) complexity

So this has worst case performance bounded by O(n^2) and is in fact an implementation of naive search algorithm. If you want to see O(n)/O(mn) I advise checking out [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to copy the whole list, use `.index` with start index specified.

```
last_index = 0
for i in subStr:
    try:
        last_index = fn.index(i, last_index) + 1
    except ValueError:
        print ("can't dup")
        sys.exit()
else:
    #string matches
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to know if it is O(n) or O(N^2)